# Insert-Statement does not work - no error message

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, insert

I'm new to this site, but i hope some of you can help me by solving my problem :)

I want to save data in an sql-database through an insert-statement, I already made it in the same way for another table, where it works well.
The Visual Web Developer doesn't reports an error message, though the insert inserts no data.

here is some of my code:

```
public void saveAnswers()
{
    //hier erfolgt das Speichern der Fragen/Antworten in die DB
    List<Question> questionlist = (List<Question>)HttpContext.Current.Session["question"];
    int SurveyID = GetSurveyId(); //SurveyID ist für alle Response-Datensätze gleich


    ArrayList arrAnswerID = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList arrTextID = new ArrayList();

    foreach (Question q in questionlist)
    {
        switch (q.Type)
        {
            case 2: //Freitext
                if (q.Answers.Count > 0)
                {
                    arrAnswerID.Add(0);
                    arrText.Add(q.Answers[0].Text);
                    arrTextID.Add(q.QuestionText[0].TextID);
                }
                break;
            case 3: //Matrixfrage
                foreach (QuestionText qt in q.QuestionText)
                {
                    arrAnswerID.Add(qt.SetAnswer.ID);
                    arrText.Add(qt.SetAnswer.Text);
                    arrTextID.Add(qt.TextID);
                }
                break;
            default: //Einfachauswahl oder Mehrfachauswahl
                foreach (Answer a in q.Answers)
                    if (a.Set)
                    {
                        arrAnswerID.Add(a.ID);
                        arrText.Add(a.Text);
                        arrTextID.Add(q.QuestionText[0].TextID);
                    }
                break;
        }

        //Datenbankzugriff
        for (int i = 0; i < arrAnswerID.Count; i++)
        {
            Command.Connection.Close();
            Command = new SqlCommand();
            Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Response (ResponseID, SurveyID, TextID, AnswerID, Text, Comment) VALUES (@ResponseID, @SurveyID, @TextID, @AnswerID, @Text, @Comment)";

            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseID", GetResponseId());
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurveyID", SurveyID);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextID", arrTextID[i]);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerID", arrAnswerID[i]);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", arrText[i].ToString());
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", "");

            Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command.Connection = conn;
            Command.Connection.Open();

            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Command.Connection.Close();
        }
        arrAnswerID.Clear();
        arrText.Clear();
        arrTextID.Clear();
    }
}
```

If you need further information, let me know, i'm already looking forward for your answers.
have a nice day

Comment: Are you sure that the query gets executed at all? The way you are opening and closing connections might create problems. Try setting a breakpoint at the start of your method and going step by step to see what happens.

Comment: why *are* you opening and closing the connection inside the loop? just open it before the `foreach` and close it after... I'm very suspicious of the way that `Command` seems to be a long-lived object, though... how and where is `Command` declared?

Comment: the debugger goes to the Command.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Just saying... with "dapper", that entire "Datenbankzugriff" content could be just `conn.Execute("INSERT INTO Response (ResponseID, SurveyID, TextID, AnswerID, Text, Comment) VALUES (@ResponseID, @SurveyID, @TextID, @AnswerID, @Text, @Comment)", new {ResponseID = GetResponseId(), SurveyID, TextID = (int)arrTextID[i], AnswerID = (int)arrAnswerId[i], Text = (string)arrText[i], Comment = "" });`

Comment: @MarcGravell, the command is recreated inside the loop. However I concur with you that this code is asking for trouble. (the first line inside the loop is a bit questionable)

Comment: @Steve ah, indeed; didn't spot that `new`.

Comment: Are you sure this code isn't simply throwing an exception that you are **swallowing** at a higher level? What happens when you debug with a breakpoint and step through?

Comment: the arraylists get cleared after each iteration, the SurveyID is meant to be redundant, the ResponseID is different in every iteration.

the conn.Execute command doesn't work :/

Comment: what makes you think it "doesn't work" ? the best thing to check would be: immediately after the insert, simply check (via ADO.NET) whether it is there, via `select`! Is there maybe a transaction somewhere that isn't getting committed? Or an "instead of" trigger at the database layer that is dropping it? Basically, that code should either work or throw an exception, so we need more info to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

could you check what is return by Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

also to debug you can use sql profiler [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step) is step by step guide which will let you know if the insert statement going to sql or not

Comment: Took the words out of my mouth... Profiler (if you have the permissions against the DB in question) is usually one of my first todo's in thie case...

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite your loop code in this way

```
    // Local variable SqlCommand
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
    // Text and Comment columns in square brackets, not sure for Comment,
    // but Text is a word used by T-SQL
    Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Response (ResponseID, SurveyID, TextID, " + 
                              "AnswerID, [Text], [Comment]) VALUES (@ResponseID, @SurveyID, " + 
                              "@TextID, @AnswerID, @Text, @Comment)";

    // Optimization, create parameters only one time
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseID", -1);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurveyID", SurveyID);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextID", -1);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerID", -1]);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", string.Empty);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", string.Empty);
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Command.Connection = conn;
    Command.Connection.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrAnswerID.Count; i++)
    {
        Command.Parameters["@ResponseID"].Value = GetResponseId();
        Command.Parameters["@TextID"].Value = arrTextID[i];
        Command.Parameters["@AnswerID"].Value = arrAnswerID[i];
        Command.Parameters["@Text"].Value = arrText[i].ToString();
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Command.Connection.Close();
```